# Replace a hash if key is present and insert if not

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes, and a hash:

```
original = [{"a"=>1}, {"a"=>2}]
new = {"a"=>1, "z"=>2}
```

I want to replace a hash in `original` if it has a particular value for key `"a"`, suppose `1`. And if this key value pair is not present, then I want to insert that hash as another element. The result should be:

```
original = [{"a"=>1, "z"=>2},{"a"=>2}]
```

And if `new` is as follows:

```
new = {"a"=>2, "z"=>2}
```

then I want `original` to become:

```
original = [{"a"=>2, "z"=>2},{"a"=>1},{"a"=>2}]
```

How do I do this without iteration? I tried the following code, but insertion does not take place when that key value pair is absent. How can I do it in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Ruby's `has_key?` method, it will return `true` or `false`. For example

```
new = {"a"=>2, "z"=>2}

if new.has_key?("a")
  # do this
else
  # do this
end
```